# Multiple scripts linked in header

Tags: jquery, vbulletin

on my forum i got multiple jquery versions linked in the header.
Most of them are from plugins i've installed earlier and they inserted automatically.

My question is, will this different versions of jquery interact with eachother
and maybe stop some scripts from working correclty or working at all?

Wouldn't only 1 jquery version work for all these plugins and my own scripts?

Regards,
Sev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loading multiple jQuery libraries can result in unexpected behaviors. its better to use [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).